# Edmx missing foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx, database-first

I am mapping my database using Entity Framework, using the database-first approach.

The problem is that the `edmx` file that should be mapping my exact database is missing some FK relations between the tables, which causes me to change my queries, because I can't approach the related tables directly.

Of course changing it directly in the classes code, it's erased every time I change something in the database (the `edmx` is recreated).

I need help please!!!

Comment: If you have no alternative but to add the keys manually perhaps try adding them into a custom "partial" class with the same name as the Entity this should stop them getting blown away.

Answer (score 4):

When you create the model from the database, there is a checkbox marked "Include Foriegn Key columns In The Model" - Make sure this is checked.

See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/11/06/foreign-key-relationships-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) for more info.

Comment: yes it is checked. someof the Foreign Keys are shown but some just refuse to be shown.

Comment: What database are you mapping to? - as in MS-Sql, MySql, oracle etc